# How to set a page as startpage in EPIServer

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have created a CMS site with 4 pages in EPIServer. Now I want to set the page with id '5' as the start page. in episerver.config section I am not finding the sitesettings section . I am developing the MVC application template provided by .NET. But not getting any option for setting pagesstarid. Where to set taht in episever.config file.

My configuration file is like this:

```
<episerver xmlns="http://EPiServer.Configuration.EPiServerSection">
  <workflowSettings>
    <workflowHost type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.AspNetWorkflowManager,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation" />
    <definitions>
      <!-- definition:           Workflow definitions that should be predefined, that is if no definition with
                                 specified type exists it will be created-->
      <!-- 
              <definition name="Sequential Approval"    description="A sequential approval workflow for pages"          type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.SequentialApproval,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation"/>
              <definition name="Parallel Approval"      description="A paralell approval workflow for pages"            type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.ParallelApproval,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation"/>
              <definition name="Request for feedback"   description="Assigns request for feedback tasks to users/roles" type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.RequestForFeedback,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation"/>
              <definition name="Ready for translation"  description="Assigns translation tasks to users/roles"          type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.ReadyForTranslation,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation"/>
        -->
    </definitions>
    <externalServices>
      <!-- externalService:      Custom services that is to be registered with workflow runtime-->
      <externalService type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.ApprovalService,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation" />
      <externalService type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.ReadyForTranslationService,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation" />
      <externalService type="EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation.Workflows.RequestForFeedbackService,EPiServer.WorkflowFoundation" />
    </externalServices>
    <references>
      <!-- reference:            References for xoml based workflows, used at compiling of xoml based workflows-->
      <!-- reference path="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysiste\bin\customdependency.dll" /-->
    </references>
  </workflowSettings>
  <applicationSettings httpCacheability="Public" pageValidateTemplate="false" uiShowGlobalizationUserInterface="true" urlRebaseKind="ToRootRelative" uiUrl="~/EPiServer/CMS/" utilUrl="~/util/" />
</episerver>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EPiServer 7, you can change the start page if you go to admin mode / config / Manage websites.
Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: You need to be aware that this will reload your web.config, in other words, the application pool of your website will be restarted - so don't do this in production environments. You can find the setting in the EPiServer.config file under the sitesettings node. It's called pageStartId

Comment: @Tchami, In the latest version of EPiServer 7, site definitions have moved from config to database. More info on the following link: http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Upgrading/EPiServer-CMS/75/Breaking-changes/